# Exporting table contain 'date' field from access to csv

Tags: mysql, csv, ms-access, export-to-csv

I have a table that contain date in access, but the data type is number (double) and the format is m/d/yyyy (not short date, general date, etc). When I try to export it out as .csv file, the format is change into 5 digit numbers. So, for example 12/12/2016 become 42716, while 7/12/2016 become 42711. The problem is, I want to import this table to MySQL with this following SQL script:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE customer FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
(
    ID, name, @var1, age
)
SET date = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

This script works well if the date format is still fine. But, if it is changed into those digit numbers, it is not work. Any idea how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use your table as source in a select query in Access and export this query.

Export the date field using this expression: `Format([YourDateField], "yyyy-mm-dd")`

This text format for the date values, MySQL should be able to read "as is", meaning you should not need the last "SET Date" part in your load script.